# ERROR TYPE: System.IO.PathTooLongException FROM IP ADDRESS: 157.55.39.175 AKA Microsoft Bingbot

Tags: c#, .net, pathtoolongexception, bingbot

The details of the error notification are below.  My question is how can I curtail the overwhelming number of Exceptions generated by Bingbots?  What do I stand to lose, if anything, by doing so?

System.IO.PathTooLongException

IP ADDRESS: 157.55.39.175
USER: guest

ERROR TYPE: System.IO.PathTooLongException
MESSAGE: Path too long
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
STACK TRACE: at System.IO.Path.SafeSetStackPointerValue(Char* buffer, Int32 index, Char value) at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck) at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath) at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath) at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_PhysicalPath() at Jenzabar.Portal.Framework.Web.Modules.AuthenticationModule.context_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
QueryString/Form Values
t   2
ALL_HTTP    HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:no-cache HTTP_CONNECTION:Keep-Alive HTTP_PRAGMA:no-cache HTTP_ACCEPT:*/* HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate HTTP_FROM:bingbot(at)microsoft.com

REMOTE_ADDR 157.55.39.175
REQUEST_METHOD  GET

URL /ics/students/jfx/extensions/webeditors/ui/common/scripts/jfx/extensions/webeditors/ui/common/scripts/jfx/extensions/feedback/jfx/ui/common/scripts/clientconfig/htmlcontent/scripts/ui/common/scripts/jfx/extensions/directorysearch/directorysearch.js

HTTP_FROM   bingbot(at)microsoft.com

Comment: You'd think the bingbot developers would try not to generate exceptions documented in msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: Hmm, somebody at /ics/students ought to fix this.  If it is not Bing then Google's bot will trigger this exact same exception.

Comment: Google's bots have not.

Comment: Adding a robots.txt file to the domain stopped the bingbot! i.e. www.domain.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-agent: bingbot

 
Disallow: /

Comment: This is all you need in a robots.txt file to fend off the evil bingbot

Comment: If you want your site to be found by users using Bing this probably isn't the best solution, perhaps just disallow certain paths that bingbot has trouble with? assuming those paths are just resources such as .js and .css (but ideally bingbot should be able to download these also )